# Using of PHP constants in foreach loop

Tags: php

I need to use PHP contants in foreach loop:

```
define('WEBS', 'http://google.com, http://yahoo.com');
foreach (WEBS as $a) {
    //do something
}
```

However I managed to do that by following code, although it works fine but aptana editor shows syntax error. Please guide me how to do that in the correct manner.

```
foreach (get_defined_constants(true)['user']['WEBS'] as $w) {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to `explode` the values first

```
foreach (explode(', ', WEBS) as $url) { ...
```

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will break a string into an array so that you can iterate through it

---

Alternatively, you could even use `preg_split`.

```
foreach(preg_split('/,\s*/', WEBS) as $url) { ...
```

[`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) allows you to split your string based on a regular expression. It returns an array. As an example, using this regex, the space following the comma is optional.

```
# a string like this
foo.com, hello.com,world.com,  test.com

# would still split properly to
[
  'foo.com',
  'hello.com',
  'world.com',
  'test.com'
]
```

Regex methods are not always necessary. But I thought I'd show you that a little more control is available when it's necessary.

---

Aptana is showing you an error because you can't use `[]` after a `func()` prior to PHP 5.4. To get around that, you can do things like:

```
$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
$constants['user']['WEBS'];
```

But in this case `WEBS` should be just fine. The only issue you were having is that you needed to convert the string to an array first.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like misuse of constants.

It seems you need a regular variable of array type.

```
$webs = array('http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com');
foreach ($webs as $a) {
    //do something
}
```

If you still thinks that constants is what you need - better ask another question, explaining why so, and be told of what you're doing wrong